# How can I print to two printers of the same model without having to reconfigure the model each time?

Tags: printing

I have a printer `HP LaserJet 1020` installed locally (USB).

In my environment, I am having to sometimes use another printers of the same type/model
on the same machine (i.e. just another `HP LaserJet 1020`). So printer driver would be 100% the same.

but if I just unplug the first `HP LaserJet 1020` and plug another `HP LaserJet 1020` (to the same USB port) it wouldn't print.

I am having to either install it as separate printer or modify existing printer to use another connection.

I understand this is rather a "feature" allowing to use multiple printers of the same type simultenously. But I really need to be able to use one connection for the same printer model.

So I could plug the same printers without re configuring them each time I want to use.

I already looked at all possible settings in `cupsd.conf` and `printers.conf` and wasn't able to find appropriate setting to achieve this.

Comment: is it critical you use the same usb port for both? when you use a different port, does it work the way it should?

Comment: @amc it's not critical to use the same USB port. And no, it doesn't work when using different USB port. I can use one of other of those 3 USB ports. No problem.

Comment: Here is the deal! The question is eligible for bounty only in two days. And I am going to provide 100 points to resolve this issue. If you answer right now I would give 150 points (just would start a bounty and then give you 150 points tomorrow)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear: I meant, can you use each printer when they are plugged into different (and separate) ports? I know it's not the answer you want, but why not keep them both plugged into separate USB ports?

Comment: what does
`sudo cat /etc/cups/printers.conf`
tell you? are each of the printer s identified as being different?

Comment: @amc yes they works both if plugged they both plugged in, but in this case I need to setup each of them. Answering to the last question is "no, I can't use both of them" Imagine that I have a hundreds of such printers. And I need to quickly test them. So I don't have only two. In case of 100s of printers I would need to setup each of them.

Comment: @amc I can't give the contents of the printers.conf at the moment (I am not at work currently)

Comment: my .conf file shows uuid and a deviceURI (withe serial) which I assume would be different for each printer

Comment: have you tried adding the printer as a class rather than as a printer?

Comment: @amc right. I tried to remove them already and play with this setting

Comment: @amc how to add the printer as a class???? One moment sir, let me investigate quickly.

Comment: @amc damnit, can't test right away. But if it helps I would give you 150 points as agreed.

Comment: Alright, adding as a class requires printers to be installed and then you would assign them to the class. It's not what I need and not what is the question about.

Comment: My `printers.conf` shows only a model identification, not a serial number: `DeviceURI usb://Samsung/ML-2850%20Series` (you'd have to adjust for your printer, of course).

Comment: @Gilles actually I tried to omit the serial number with no success. At least HP printers don't support this. May be Samsungs don't have serial numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found out that it's not possible normally. Because every **DeviceURI** must contain serial number of the printer. You can't just remove the serial number part from **DeviceURI**

here you can read official answer to the question: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.printing.cups.general/29486

> This is not supported directly by CUPS, but third-party add-ons may be
>   able to provide this functionality.

But I couldn't find any such add-ons.

---

Here are the possible solutions from me:

**Solution 1**

You can create your own backend: http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Using_Your_Own_Backends_to_Print_with_CUPS#A_careless_backend_for_a_single_USB_printer

however this didn't work for me..

**Solution 2**

Use UDEV rules. So whenever printers connects you would rewrite the **printers.conf** and the **DeviceURI** to the newly connected one. This worked for me, but wasn't reliable.

**Solution 3**
You can try to write your own addon to CUPS. f you are a programmer
http://cups.org/documentation.php/api-cups.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same problem and found this post useful, [this is the solution I created for my problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/632405/453912), hope it helps.

It basically uses this one liner to get the wanted printer and update CUPS configuration.

```
lpadmin -p PRINTER_NAME -v $(lpinfo -v | grep usb://PRINTER_MODEL | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
```